# Signature of function when sets have different cardinality

Tags: functions, notation

I'm trying to formally define a function I've programmed in Java. The actual function is far more complex but let suppose the function receives an integer and produces a set of integers as result. **The cardinality of the returned set is different for each input value**.

```
Set<Integer> f(int x) {
    Set s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; ++i){ 
        s.add(i);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Is it correct to define the function as following? Does this function imply that all returned sets have the same cardinality?

$$f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^n$$

Is it better to define a variable, let say $\mathbb{M}$, as all the possible sets of integers and define the function as following?

$$f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{M}$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb N^n$ is the set of all ordered $n$-tuples of natural numbers, which is not what you intended.

Your second idea is correct. Note that the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ is often denoted $2^\mathbb N$. Also, the set of all integers is denoted by $\mathbb Z$, not $\mathbb N$ (which is the natural numbers). You could say that $f:\mathbb Z \to 2^\mathbb Z$.

Comment: It's also denoted $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ or similar ("P" for "power-set").